# Where to find tomcat service configuration file on file system?

Tags: tomcat

When //ES//TomcatService command is executed, we get GUI tool where we can set different configuration. I would like to know where these details are store on my system?

Answer (score 0):

All the windows service details are stored in the windows registry. If Tomcat is installed as a service, it details are stored at  **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tomcat9.13** as shown in the screen.

[image]